Do i need formula evaluation while SAX parsing of a XLSX file
In XLSX file, <f> tag is used for formulas and <v> tag seems to be used for the value computed of that formula in some spreadsheet software. I m writing a SAX Parser for xlsx reading. So while reading, can I directly use the value in <v> tag when <f> tag is encountered, or do I need to store the formula somewhere and evaluate it and get the value by myself. Is it safe to read the value from <v> tag for formula cells.
            <c r="L4" s="0" t="s">
                <v>25</v>
            </c>
            <c r="M4" s="0" t="n">
                <f aca="false">SUM(M2:M3)</f>
                <v>6</v>
            </c>
            <c r="N4" s="3" t="n">
                <v>500</v>
            </c>


Is "the value the last time that Excel bothered to recalculate it" good enough? Or do you always need the latest formula result, eg for dates?

Have you considered using Apache POI to read the spreadsheet instead?

@Gagravarr its good enough to use the already calculated one. My doubt is, will there be in any case, the <v> tag not having the computed formula value.

@lance-java yes, but it causes OOM issues, so going to read through a sax parser.

POI has a SAX API

https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/ streams the xlsx (using the POI SAX API under the hood) - but avoids you having to write all the SAX logic for yourself

@lance-java yes, I m using those only. But my doubt is do I have to recalculate the value of the formula, during streaming. Is that necessary or I can just use the value in  tag itself.

The "v" value can be used instead of evaluating the formula. The "v" value can have lots of different formats. The Excel data format is pretty complicated. I would recommend using a lib like fastexcel or excel-streaming-reader instead. Have a look at https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader/blob/bb15c770df7549c9ed74307059c19c14cc0cede3/src/main/java/com/github/pjfanning/xlsx/impl/StreamingRowIterator.java

Thanks @PJFanning, I will discuss with my fellow members if we can use this library in our application.
